# Could we say "invest something in somebody"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Ok, now, in [the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/invest?q=invest)

> **invest** [intransitive, transitive] to buy property, shares in a company, etc. in the hope of making a profit
>
> **invest (in something)**
>
> *Now is a good time to invest in the property market.*
>
> **invest something (in something)**
>
> *He invested his life savings in his daughter's business.*

Ok, let say we've known a child who has great soccer skills but he is poor & he can not afford to join a well-known training school. Now, we want to pay all the school fee for him & he will pay us a lot of money back in the future when he is famous.

My question is:

Could we say "*I want to invest money on him*"?

We also have the structure "**invest somebody (with something)**" in [the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/invest?q=invest)

> [transitive] (formal) to give somebody power or authority, especially
>   as part of their job
>
> **invest somebody (with something)** *The new position invested her with a
>   good deal of responsibility.*
>
> **invest somebody (as something)** *The interview was broadcast on the same
>   day he was invested as President.*

But the structure "**invest somebody (with something)**" does not carry the meaning that we make some profit in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually you can.  I don't know if the usage is recent (and idiomatic) but for example you can "invest *time* in someone (or something)":

> I **invested a lot of time in Sheila**, grooming her for the executive position, but she turned out to be a poor fit for the role.

The metaphor is that time is a valuable commodity like any other, and you can choose to *invest* it in a person, project, or entity, to (hopefully) produce some kind of profitable return.